# PostgreSQL list companies and rank by sales

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

So I have:

```
companies (id, name, tenant_id)
invoices (id, company_id, tenant_id, total)
```

What I want to do is return a result set like:

```
company    |   Feb Sales  | Feb Rank   | Lifetime Sales | Lifetime Rank
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
ABC Comp   |  1,000       | 1          |  2,000         | 2
XYZ Corp   |    500       | 2          |  5,000         | 1
```

I can do the sales totals using subselects, but when I do the rank always returns 1. I'm assuming because it only returns 1 row per subselect so will always be the top row?

Here is a piece of the sql:

```
SELECT
"public".companies."name",
(
    SELECT
        rank() OVER (PARTITION BY i.tenant_id ORDER BY sum(grand_total) DESC) AS POSITION
    FROM
        invoices i 
    where 
        company_id = companies.id
    group by
        i.tenant_id, i.company_id
)
from companies
```

Comment: You need to rank in outer SELECT and use sub-query just for calculating sums.

Comment: Right so I was selecting the company table as my main, but should select the invoices and rank on them? How do I do 2 rankings though e.g Month / lifetime?

Comment: The same way you plan to calculate two totals.

Comment: If I do that, I get all 1's again :|

companies.name,
 
 (
  SELECT
   rank() OVER (PARTITION BY i.tenant_id ORDER BY sum(grand_total) DESC) AS POSITION
  
 ) AS rank

Comment: You will move your sub-query into `FROM`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59557/discussion-between-pm-77-1-and-brettski).

Comment: There is no date information in the invoice table. How is it possible to discriminate February?

Comment: What is `Feb Sales` supposed to be? Your question is incomplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is untested version that can have typos.  Please treat it just as description of the approach.  For simplicity I assumed that `invoices` have a `month` column.

```
SELECT
    "public".companies."name", 
     rank() OVER (PARTITION BY sales.companies ORDER BY sales.lifetime) As "Lifetime Rank",
     rank() OVER (PARTITION BY sales.companies ORDER BY sales.month As "One Month"

FROM companies LEFT JOIN 
   (
    SELECT
        SUM(grand_total) As Lifetime,
        SUM(CASE WHEN i.month = <the month of report>, grand_total, 0) As Month
    FROM
        invoices i 
    GROUP BY company_id
   ) sales
ON companies.company_id = sales.company_id
```

If you run into problems, add the actual code that you used and sample data to your post and I will attempt to create a live demo for you.

Comment: So this works now. I guess one thing I needed to tweak was the fact that the tenant_id comes into play, after fixing the typos, it works :)